# How is this proof that monomorphisms in $\bf Set$ are injective sufficiently general?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, category-theory, proof-explanation

An arrow $\phi:A\to B$ in a category is monic if and only if for any object $X$ and all arrows $x,y:X\to A$ it follows that $\phi\circ x=\phi\circ y \implies x=y$.

As follows is the proof I have seen in multiple sources that the monomorphisms in the category of sets are injective. I am struggling with the generality of the portion following “(?).”

> **Proof.** Let $\phi:A\rightarrowtail B$ be a monomorphism in $\bf Set$.
> If $A$ has one element, the result is apparent; hence presume $a_1,a_2\in A$ with $a_1\neq a_2$. We aim to show that it follows that $\phi(a_1)\neq\phi(a_2)$, by definition of injection.
>
> **(?)** Considering a singleton $\{e\}=X$, define the arrows $x:X\to A:e\mapsto a_1$ and $y:X\to A:e\mapsto a_2$.
>
> By design $x\neq y$, so $\phi\circ x\neq\phi\circ y$ since $\phi$ is monic. These composite functions must be unequal at the only point in their domain:
> $$\begin{align}
> \phi\circ x(e) &\neq \phi\circ y(e) \\
> \phi(a_1) &\neq \phi(a_2) \tag*{$\blacksquare$}
> \end{align}$$

This proof does not appear valid for *all* arrows in $\bf Set$ with target $A$. Rather, it seems specific to functions with a singleton domain.

Could someone please explain how this proof is sufficiently general?

Comment: How does it apply to any object $X$ when the proof only considers $X$ having one element? @EeveeTrainer

Comment: the proof shows that *if* $\phi$ is not injective, then it is *not* a monomorphism. By contrapositive, this shows that *if* $\phi$ is a monomorphism, then it is injective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't trying to prove anything for all objects $X.$ You're trying to prove that $\phi(a_1)\ne \phi(a_2)$ when $a_1\ne a_2,$ using the *assumption* that for all objects $X$ and all functions $x,y:X\to A,$ $\phi\circ x=\phi\circ y\implies x=y.$ In particular, this assumption holds when $X=\{e\},$ which is all that is needed for the result. The converse of your theorem is thus the harder direction.

Answer (score 2):

The proof should be "fully general" in the sense that it applies to a monomorphism $\phi : A \to B$ regardless of what $A$ and $B$ are. This criterion is satisfied.

The definition of a monomorphism says that $\phi$ has a certain property for *all* choices of $X$ and for all $x,y : X \to A$. Since we know $\phi$ is a monomorphism, we may apply this property for our choice of $X$ and $x,y$.

If we wanted to *prove* that $\phi$ is a monomorphism, then we would have to be "fully general" by considering *all* possible $X$ (and all possible $x,y : X \to A$). But that's not what we're doing here.