Szekeres proof that in the category of sets a morphism is a monomorphism iff it is injective
In "A Course in Modern Mathematical Physics", Peter Szekeres gives a proof of the statement "In the case of the category of sets a morphism $A \xrightarrow{\phi} B$ is a monomorphism if and only if it is a one-to-one mapping." The proof is as follows:


If $\phi : A \to B$ is one-to-one then for any pair of maps $\alpha : X \to A$ and $\alpha' : X \to A$,
$$
\begin{equation*}
  \phi(\alpha(x)) = \phi(\alpha'(x)) \implies \alpha(x) = \alpha'(x)
\end{equation*}
$$
for all $x \in X$. This is simply another way of stating the monomorphism property $\phi \circ \alpha = \phi \circ \alpha' \implies \alpha = \alpha'$.
Conversely, suppose $\phi$ is a monomorphism. Since $X$ is an arbitrary set, in the definition of the monomorphism property, we may choose it to be a singleton $X = \{x\}$. For any pair of points $a, a' \in A$ deﬁne the maps $\alpha, \alpha' : X \to A$ by setting $\alpha(x) = a$ and $\alpha' (x) = a'$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
  \phi(a) = \phi(a') &\implies \phi \circ \alpha(x) = \phi \circ \alpha'(x)\\
  &\implies \phi \circ \alpha = \phi \circ \alpha'\\
  &\implies \alpha = \alpha'\\
  &\implies a = \alpha(x) = \alpha'(x) = a'.\\
\end{align*}
$$
Hence $\phi$ is one-to-one.


If we define $P$ as the statement "$\phi$ is injective" and $Q$ as the statement "$\phi$ is a monomorphism", then I believe part (1) of the proof is a proof of $P \implies Q$ and part (2) is a proof of $Q \implies P$, which together prove $P \iff Q$.
That all seems fine and I don't have any problems with part (1) of the proof.
However, in part (2) I'm having trouble with the statement "Since $X$ is an arbitrary set, in the definition of the monomorphism property, we may choose it to be a singleton $X = \{x\}$." It seems we're proving $Q \implies P$ in the specific case that $X$ is a singleton. But, the definition of a monorphism according to Szekeres (and I've seen the same definition elsewher) is: "A morphism $A \xrightarrow{\phi} B$ is called a monomorphism if for any object $X$ and morphisms $X \xrightarrow{\alpha} A$ and $X \xrightarrow{\alpha'} A$ we have that $\phi \circ \alpha = \phi \circ \alpha' \implies \alpha = \alpha'$." So, we have to show this for arbitrary $X$ but $X$ being a singleton is a particular case. Therefore, this proof seems incomplete. Am I correct? If so, how can I prove this in the general case? If not, what have I misunderstood?

My mistake, this question is a duplicate. It was already asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4265394.
